# Install timer/clock ISR on Windows - Asynchronous call in a single threaded environment

Tags: c, windows, timer, operating-system, interrupt

I'm refining some code which simulated a context-switching scheduler on x86 Windows systems. The program compiles on Windows XP (Edit: probably not Windows 7) with some ancient Borland C compiler, and is being ported to being MSVC compilable.

At one point, the code installs ISRs through these unavailable functions in `dos.h`:

```
void (*)() getvect(int)
void setvect(int, void (*)());
```

Specifically, the code installs an ISR for a (cyclic) timer interrupt. The calls are:

```
tick_isr_old = getvect(0x08);
setvect(0xF2, tick_isr_old);
setvect(0x08, (void interrupt (*)(void)) tick_isr);
setvect(0xF1, (void interrupt (*)(void)) context_switch_isr);
```

Does anyone have any idea what would be a reasonable way to set those ISRs (with the Windows API maybe?). To make things worse, the functions are implemented in assembly language (they need to perform a context switch after all...). Is there at least any documentation which interrupt vectors the integer constants (0x08, 0xF2, 0xF1) refer to? Google didn't really come up with something I could work with.

---

**UPDATE**: Since it is apparently not possible to get those DOS calls working in Windows 7, I need a way to asynchronously call a function in a generally single threaded environment.

Under linux, the `signal()` and `raise()` functions can do this, but under Windows they are only supported in the most minimal way that is possible. Is there a way to achieve that under Windows?

Comment: Is the Borland compiler building a Windows application or a DOS application?  If DOS, it's the DOS emulator built into Windows that's doing all the magic here.  If Windows, can you show us the code in tick_isr and context_switch_isr?

Comment: @HarryJohnston now that you mention it, if I remember correctly it compiled as a 16 bit application (hence DOS). I think it didn't actually compile on Windows 7 either (only XP). Currently I don't have direct access to the machine it compiled on to verify this, but that would explain it. That doesn't solve the problem though, and since Windows 7 doesn't have the DOS emulator anymore (or am I wrong?), it makes it only worse since I have to find another solution :/

Comment: Windows 7 32-bit still has the DOS emulator.

Comment: For the record, if the move to Windows doesn't work out for any reason, an emulator such as DOSBox (or a VM such as Virtual PC running a real copy of DOS) would be one way to keep your code running even on 64-bit editions of Windows.  I'm not sure whether there's any way to compile DOS code with MSVC though, you might have to keep using Borland.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll definitely need to replace tick_isr and and context_switch_isr, since they're implementing context-switching for a DOS environment.  There's no way the existing code will do anything meaningful in Windows, even if you could sensibly execute it.

Since, in the original code, the context switches are preemptive, you could probably just eliminate that logic altogether and use Windows threads instead.  Presumably the existing code has some routines for creating and removing contexts, and these can be replaced with corresponding Windows API thread functions.

If you need to ensure that only one thread is running at a time, you could use [SetProcessAffinityMask](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms686223%28v=vs.85%29) to tie the process to a single CPU.

Alternatively, you could use the debugging functions [GetThreadContext](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms679362%28v=vs.85%29) and [SetThreadContext](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms680632%28v=vs.85%29) to implement your own context switching.  In this situation you would have one thread for the main program code and a second thread running the context switcher.

Comment: That sounds sensible. I think I could also manually "schedule" the threads with `SuspendThread` and `ResumeThread` (it is important that the timining in the simulator, especially context switches which are triggered by the timer ISR, are well predictable and visible). I'll give it a try to see if that works. If it does, I'm glad for not needing the assembly magic after all.

Comment: Okay it ended up working very well. Most low-level operations could be translated directly to a corresponding thread operation, and I needed only a single mutex. The system is surprisingly stable, and - most importantly - debuggable (even though it's a multi-tasking OS). The only thing I didn't find a substitution for is getting a thread's peak stack usage :(

Answer (score 1):

See the [wikipedia entry on BIOS interrupts](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BIOS_interrupt_call); it says:

> 08h​  IRQ0: Implemented by the system timing component; called 18.2 times per second (once every 55 ms) by the programmable interval timer

On Windows 7, you will need to create kernel mode drivers to access interrupts, though.

You may be able to emulate interrupts for your scheduler using Windows [user mode scheduling](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd627187%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) and [fibers](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682661%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

Comment: While I have to admit this was one of the more interesting things I've read, UMS is only available on x64 Windows. Fibers alone won't help in this case because I cannot inject a `SwitchToFiber()` to the artificial "main fiber" from a cyclic "manual timer ISR" thread (if I could that'd be awesome). I just had the alternative idea to abuse `signal()` with `SIGUSR1`, but apparently that isn't available on Windows. On a side node, that Borland compiler seems to be able to do all that without a kernel mode driver.