# Sending an integer using COM4

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2012, serial-port

```
#include <dos.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <conio.h>
#define PORT1 0x2E8 /* Port Address Goes Here */
/* Defines Serial Ports Base Address */
/* COM4 0x2E8 */
#define INTVECT 0x0B /* Com Port's IRQ here */
/* (Must also change PIC setting) */
int bufferin = 0;
int bufferout = 0;
char ch;
char buffer[1025];


void interrupt PORT1INT() /* Interrupt Service Routine (ISR) for PORT1 */
{
    int c;
    do {
        c = inportb(PORT1 + 5);
        if (c & 1) {
            buffer[bufferin] = inportb(PORT1);
            bufferin++;
            if (bufferin == 1024) bufferin = 0;
        }
    } while (c & 1);
    outportb(0x20, 0x20);
}
void main(void)
{
    int c;
    //outportb(PORT1 + 1, 0); /* Turn off interrupts - Port1 */
    //oldport1isr = getvect(INTVECT); /* Save old Interrupt Vector for */
    /* later recovery */
    setvect(INTVECT, PORT1INT); /* Set Interrupt Vector Entry */
    /* COM1 - 0x0C */
    /* COM2 - 0x0B */
    /* COM3 - 0x0C */
    /* COM4 - 0x0B */
    outportb(PORT1 +3 , 0x80); /* SET DLAB ON */
    outportb(PORT1 +0, 0x03); /* Set Baud rate - Divisor Latch Low Byte */
    /* Default 0x03 = 38,400 BPS */
    /* 0x01 = 115,200 BPS */
    /* 0x02 = 56,700 BPS */
    /* 0x06 = 19,200 BPS */
    /* 0x0C = 9,600 BPS */
    /* 0x18 = 4,800 BPS */
    /* 0x30 = 2,400 BPS */
    outportb(PORT1 + 1, 0x00); /* Set Baud rate - Divisor Latch High Byte */
    outportb(PORT1 + 3, 0x03); /* 8 Bits, No Parity, 1 Stop Bit */
    outportb(PORT1 + 2, 0xC7); /* FIFO Control Register */
    outportb(PORT1 + 4, 0x0B); /* Turn on DTR, RTS, and OUT2 */
    outportb(0x21, (inportb(0x21) & 0xF7)); /* Set Programmable Interrupt */
    /* Controller */
    /* COM1 (IRQ4) - 0xEF */
    /* COM2 (IRQ3) - 0xF7 */
    /* COM3 (IRQ4) - 0xEF */
    /* COM4 (IRQ3) - 0xF7 */
    outportb(PORT1 + 1, 0x01); /* Interrupt when data received */
    printf("\nSample Comm's Program. Press ESC to quit \n");
    do {
        if (bufferin != bufferout){
            ch = buffer[bufferout];
            bufferout++;
            if (bufferout == 1024) bufferout = 0;
            printf("%c", ch);
        }
        if (kbhit()){
            c = getch();
            outportb(PORT1, c);
        }
    } while
        (c != 27);
    outportb(PORT1 + 1, 0); /* Turn off interrupts - Port1 */
    outportb(0x21, (inportb(0x21) | 0x08)); /* MASK IRQ using PIC */
    /* COM1 (IRQ4) - 0x10 */
    /* COM2 (IRQ3) - 0x08 */
    /* COM3 (IRQ4) - 0x10 */
    /* COM4 (IRQ3) - 0x08 */
    setvect(INTVECT, oldport1isr); /* Restore old interrupt vector */
}
```

So I have to send some data from an UART to an UART using COM4 Serial Port, I have this small program here as an example but can't figure out why I can't compile it in Visual Studion ( C++ Win32 Project )

Any ideas? I also have to implement an timer with RQ3.

Comment: This is a DOS program. To use it in modern Windows you'll have to compile it with an old DOS compiler in a DOSBox (free utility, download from  [SourceForge](http://sourceforge.net/projects/dosbox/)). Well I can't say for sure that that'll work, but trying it direcly in Windows won't work for sure.

Comment: I think this is sort of the same thing as below link
[http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11870152/install-timer-clock-isr-on-windows-asynchronous-call-in-a-single-threaded-envi](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11870152/install-timer-clock-isr-on-windows-asynchronous-call-in-a-single-threaded-envi)

Answer (score 0):

It can't compile because access to the hardware is managed by the OS. Your example states in the very first line which OS it applies to, and it's not Windows.

As for your second claim, you don't. IRQ3 is not used for timers in Windows programs. There are plenty of answers about timers already on StackOverflow, so check that first.